# Get friends activities on an Open Graph website with FQL (like the Live Stream plugin but with just my friends))

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I'm building a membership website with Facebook Login. I want to display a custom designed stream (like the Live Stream plugin).

Can anybody help me with the fql-query to return the user's friends' activities (comments and likes) on this open graph enabled website?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [graph api](https://graph.facebook.com/ACTION_ID/?fields=likes,comments).

`ACTION_ID` is returned after successful action post